# C programming on PI using VS-Code. Get "undefined reference to '...' " when using the quote form of the include directive

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to program a PI via VS-Code. When I translate the program I get "undefined referenc to `...' ". It seems that the header files that I include via #include "..." are not translated. If I translate the data in the terminal and then link the headers afterwards, it works. If I have understood correctly, you can set this via the tasks.json. However, I have not yet found out how.

I would like to modify an existing C program that has already been programmed on a PI. The programming is to be done in VS-Code via SSH. However, as soon as I try to run the program, I get numerous error messages with "undefined reference to '...' ".

Even with the minimal program helloworld I get this notification as soon as I want to include local .h-files with #include "...". System files with #include <..> are found.

The following programme

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

is translated without problems.

However, as soon as I add Messages.h

```c
#ifndef MESSAGES_H_INCLUDED
    #define MESSAGES_H_INCLUDED


void printMsg(char *str);
#endif // MESSAGES_H_INCLUDED
```

and Messages.c

```c
#include "Messages.h"

void printMsg(char *str)
{
    printf("Testausgabe: %s\n",str);
}
```

to the project and to the program

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Messages.h"

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    printMsg("Somthing else.\n");
}
```

The compiler returns

```bash
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccBVuwoo.o: in function `main':
helloworld.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `printMsg'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And this although all files are stored in the same folder.

If I create the files manually using the terminal and then link them, it works.

```bash
$ gcc -c helloworld.c
$ gcc -c Messages.h
$ gcc -o Hello helloworld.o Messages.o
```

Does this mean that I have to manually create a make file that I have to expand for each new header (that would be a bummer)? Couldn't this also be done automatically via VS-Code? Have I perhaps overlooked something here? Sorry, but I am very new to this.

I am grateful for any help.

Attached is also the automatically generated tasks.json from VSC.

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc Aktive Datei kompilieren",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Vom Debugger generierte Aufgabe."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```